# IPactBuilderV3 (and PactNet.Native) unresolved

Tags: pact-net

I've downloaded PactNet and PactNet.Windows NuGet packages. But [Consumer.tests.ApiTest.cs](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-workshop-dotnet-core-v3/blob/master/Consumer/tests/ApiTest.cs) code  has this compiler error. I'm unable to clone GitHub repo due to company security policies. I have to get the samples running manually.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake: Documentation was talking about installing pre-release packages. Installed PackNet pre-release and voila.

[PackNet.Native still unresolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882951/unable-to-install-packnet-native-nuget-package) though. I just commented it out. Seems to be unused.